# In Eclipse, get error "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" when upload .war to weblogic

Tags: eclipse, maven, weblogic

I have a weblogic server 10.3.6 running in my eclipse. I am using maven 3.1.1 with jdk1.7.0_80. Upon maven build, I've ensured that these parameters are set. In preferences, i've made sure that they are the same. However, I get the error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 when I try to upload the resulting .war file in weblogic. Is my IDE looking at some config files other than what's stated in the preferences?

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that you have compiled your code with a newer version of java than your web logic supports running (without telling it to behave as an older version).

Switch to the same version of java for compiling and the error should go away.